# how to use a macro in ant tasks not supporting "alien" nested elements

Tags: java, ant, build, build-automation

What I am trying to do is to reduce redundancy in my build files. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out a way to circumvent ant's restrictions on nested elements. 
One example is externalizing the filling of the MANIFEST, which is the same for all .jars and .ears. 
I define a macro, encapsulating the `manifest` task with a `sequential`, but trying to use it in a `jar` task obviously results in a

> jar doesn't support the nested "createManifest" element".

Is there a sane way around these restrictions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Could you instead write a macrodef to template your required jar task, including your standardized manifest section there, rather than in its own macrodef.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have already reduced the creation of jars to a template-like target which is imported by the individual projects. And I have a similar target for the ears. The two are different except for the manifest part, so I wanted to create a macro for both. Thus if I macro-ify the jar and the ear task separately I still have to repeat the manifest part.